# Locking with hibernate and thread

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

I have used multiple syncronized thread for processing multiple transaction and these transaction geting from database by using hibernate framwork and used locking concept.
Problem is,each thread process 1st time correctally but next time its throw SQL 01002 and SQL 72000
exception. Please look into the code-

```
    long _StartTimeForMe = System.currentTimeMillis();

    boolean _contextPushed;
    txContext =
        GlobalFunctions.generateId(
            true,
            DataBrokerConstants.CONTEXT_PREFIX,
            null,
            null);
    txContext = this.getName() + txContext;
    logger_U.pushContext(txContext);
    _contextPushed = true;

    try
    {
        coreSession = openTxCoreSession();
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        logger_U.info("exception while creating Tx_Core session");
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        stagSession = openStagSession();
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e2)
    {
        logger_U.info("exception while creating stag session");
        e2.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    String _txContextBackup = txContext;

    int i = 1;
    long _timeElapsedByMe = System.currentTimeMillis() - _StartTimeForMe;

    try
    {
        while (doIhaveMoreTime(_timeElapsedByMe))
        {
            txContext = _txContextBackup + "-" + (i);
            logger_U.removeContext();
            logger_U.pushContext(txContext);

            coreTransaction = null;
            stagTransaction = null;

            InnerClassUpdate _rec = null;
            UpdateRecord _r = null;
            if (null != coreSession)
            {
                coreTransaction = coreSession.beginTransaction();
                _rec = getURForUpdates(coreSession);
            }
            else
            {
                logger_U.error("coreSession is not created.");
                break;
            }

            if (null != _rec)
            {
                _r = _rec.record;
                logger_U.info(
                    "record found. Going to process Record: ID = "
                        + _r.getId()
                        + " TX_IDENTIFIER = "
                        + _r.getTxIdentifier()
                        + "UPDATE_TYPE = "
                        + _r.getUpdateType());

                //If a record of same transaction is processing or has been processed before in same run, it will not run again in this run
                if (isTxProcessing(_r.getTxIdentifier()))
                {
                    if (coreTransaction != null
                        && !coreTransaction.wasCommitted()
                        && !coreTransaction.wasRolledBack())
                        coreTransaction.rollback();

                    if (stagTransaction != null
                        && !stagTransaction.wasCommitted()
                        && !stagTransaction.wasRolledBack())
                        stagTransaction.rollback();

                    logger_U.debug(
                        "A record of Tx_Identifier : "
                            + _r.getTxIdentifier()
                            + " is either processing or has been processed in this run.");
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        stagTransaction = stagSession.beginTransaction();
                        if (processUpdates(_rec))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                if (stagTransaction != null
                                    && !stagTransaction.wasCommitted()
                                    && !stagTransaction.wasRolledBack())
                                {
                                    stagTransaction.commit();

                                    logger_U.debug("stag commit success");
                                }
                                if (coreTransaction != null
                                    && !coreTransaction.wasCommitted()
                                    && !coreTransaction.wasRolledBack())
                                {
                                    coreTransaction.commit();

                                    logger_U.debug("core commit success");
                                }

                            }
                            catch (HibernateException e)
                            {
                                logger_U.debug("error while commit");
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (stagTransaction != null
                                && !stagTransaction.wasCommitted()
                                && !stagTransaction.wasRolledBack())
                                stagTransaction.rollback();

                            logger_U.debug("stagTransaction rollback...");
                            if (coreTransaction != null
                                && !coreTransaction.wasCommitted()
                                && !coreTransaction.wasRolledBack())
                                coreTransaction.rollback();

                            logger_U.debug("coreTransaction rolback...");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e1)
                    {
                        if (stagTransaction != null
                            && !stagTransaction.wasCommitted()
                            && !stagTransaction.wasRolledBack())
                            stagTransaction.rollback();

                        if (coreTransaction != null
                            && !coreTransaction.wasCommitted()
                            && !coreTransaction.wasRolledBack())
                            coreTransaction.rollback();

                        logger_U.error(
                            "Exception while processing UpdateRecord.");
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (stagTransaction != null
                    && !stagTransaction.wasCommitted()
                    && !stagTransaction.wasRolledBack())
                    stagTransaction.rollback();

                if (coreTransaction != null
                    && !coreTransaction.wasCommitted()
                    && !coreTransaction.wasRolledBack())
                    coreTransaction.rollback();

                logger_U.info(
                    "No record found. wait for "
                        + convertMilliesToSec(
                            DataBrokerConstants.SMALL_SLEEP)
                        + "Sec.");
                Thread.sleep(DataBrokerConstants.SMALL_SLEEP);
                i++;
                _timeElapsedByMe =
                    System.currentTimeMillis() - _StartTimeForMe;

                continue;
            }

            //No matter record is processed successfully or not, it will not be processed again in this run
            if (_rec != null && vectForUpdate.contains(_rec))
            {
                logger_U.debug(
                    "UpdateRecord of ID "
                        + _r.getId()
                        + " and TX_IDENTIFIER "
                        + _r.getTxIdentifier()
                        + " is removing from vectForUpdate.");
                removeObjectFromVect(_rec);
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            _timeElapsedByMe = System.currentTimeMillis() - _StartTimeForMe;
            i++;
        } //END while loop
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (stagTransaction != null
                && !stagTransaction.wasCommitted()
                && !stagTransaction.wasRolledBack())
                stagTransaction.rollback();

            if (coreTransaction != null
                && !coreTransaction.wasCommitted()
                && !coreTransaction.wasRolledBack())
                coreTransaction.rollback();

        }
        catch (HibernateException e3)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }
        logger_U.error("Unknown Exception occured while processing.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        txContext = _txContextBackup;
        logger_U.removeContext();
        logger_U.pushContext(txContext);
        closeSession(coreSession);
        closeSession(stagSession);
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you really want transactions and isolation to me.

Comment: What do you mean by "used locking concept"? Hibernate and your Database Engine where designed with transactions and concurrency in mind, they are already thread safe by definition. Sessions are not really thread safe, but you are not supposed to share the same session between threads.

Answer (score 2):

When using Hibernate, you should be very careful in multi-threaded environment.

- The first thing you should verify is that the transactions are correctly committed, and the SQL executed. If you cannot verify it by reading your code, you can increase the logging level of Hibernate to verify it
- Hibernate Session is not thread-safe and you are only supposed to share among threads the SessionFactory. You have also to verify that every time you open a session you take care of closing it, because this does not happen automatically and will prevent new threads to open a new Session.

Comment: thanks for valuable reply. I am using multiple session. threads come create session and the start processing within loop. Inside the loop each time new transaction is created. Please look at following sample code-

Comment: Where do you close the session?

Comment: This code is plenty of bugs and I strongly advice you to make it more modular and to handle exception in a much more elegant way. I can easily see that if openStagSession() fails, coreSession stays open because you call return; esplicitely. Furthermore, you are setting the session to null and then you are closing them . Could that work?